# Convertic non-numeric factor to numeric column with mapping in R

Tags: r

I have a factor in a `data frame` with levels like `hot`, `warm`, `tepid`, `cold`, `very cold`, `freezing`. I want to *map them to an integer column* with values in the range `[-2, 2]` for regression, with some values mapping to the same thing. I want to be able to specify the explicit mapping, so that `very hot` words map to `2`, `very cold` words to `-2`, etc. How do I do this cleanly? I would love a function that I just pass some named list to, or something.

Comment: ouch, that downvote was harsh

Comment: FYI, `[-2, 2]` represent only 5 values, while your sample levels represent 6 values.

Comment: @AnandaMahto: in effect he says "with some values mapping to the same value".

Answer (score 17):

Assume a factor vector `x` holds the categories.

```
temperatures <- c("hot", "warm", "tepid", "cold", "very cold", "freezing")
set.seed(1)
x <- as.factor(sample(temperatures, 10, replace=TRUE))
x
[1] warm     tepid    cold     freezing warm     freezing freezing cold    
[9] cold     hot     
Levels: cold freezing hot tepid warm
```

Create a numeric vector `temp.map` with the mapping. Note that "hot" and "warm" map to the same value below.

```
temp.map <- c("hot"=2, "warm"=2, "tepid"=1, "cold"=0, "very cold"=-1, "freezing"=-1)    
y <- temp.map[as.character(x)]
y
warm    tepid     cold freezing     warm freezing freezing     cold 
   2        1        0       -1        2       -1       -1        0 
cold      hot 
   0        2
```

Answer (score 8):

A factor can easily be converted to an integer using `as.integer`.

For instance:

```
>temperatures <- c("Hot", "Warm", "Tiepid", "Cold", "Very cold", "Freezing")
> set.seed(12345)
> a <- sample(temperatures, 10, r=T)
> a <- factor(a, levels = temperatures)
> a
 [1] Very cold Freezing  Very cold Freezing  Tiepid    Hot       Warm     
 [8] Cold      Very cold Freezing 
Levels: Hot Warm Tiepid Cold Very cold Freezing
> as.integer(a)
 [1] 5 6 5 6 3 1 2 4 5 6
```

If you need it in the [-2;2] range, you would just do

```
> as.integer(a)-3
  [1]  2  3  2  3  0 -2 -1  1  2  3
```

Comment: I believe this solution does not address the requirement of mapping multiple levels to the same numeric value.

Comment: @Leo: ah, did not notice that part, your solution works well for that.